# How to change "YYYY-mm-dd" date data type to a UTC Posixct data type?

Tags: r, date, posixct

I have a set of date columns that look like this

```
"2003-01-02", "2003-01-03" and so on
```

when i run

```
as.POSIXct.Date(df$date,format="%Y-%m-%d")
```

i get "2003-01-02 19:00:00 EST", "2003-01-03 19:00:00 EST" and so on.

when i run

```
as.POSIXct(df$date, format="%Y-%m-%d",tz="UTC")
```

i also get "2003-01-02 19:00:00 EST", "2003-01-03 19:00:00 EST" and so on.

I would like "2019-01-02 UTC". I've been reading other threads, but they don't address the situation as to why the dataset remains as EST no matter what tz i set.

```
structure(list(date = structure(c(12053, 12054, 12054, 
12054, 12055, 12055), class = "Date")), row.names = 4:9, class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

The notion here is to note that you do not need the time part of the date. From the documentation of `as.POXISct` we have:

> There are two POSIX date/time classes, which differ in the way that
> the values are stored internally. The POSIXct class stores date/time
> values as the number of seconds since January 1, 1970, while the
> POSIXlt class stores them as a list with elements for second, minute,
> hour, day, month, and year, among others. Unless you need the list
> nature of the POSIXlt class, the POSIXct class is the usual choice for
> storing dates in R.

It seems you need `as.POSIXlt` instead:

Thus

```
as.POSIXlt(df$STOP_FRISK_DATE, tz="UTC")
[1] "2003-01-01 UTC" "2003-01-02 UTC" "2003-01-02 UTC" "2003-01-02 UTC" "2003-01-03 UTC"
[6] "2003-01-03 UTC"
```

Comment: i want to eventually bind it with another dataset but that has data type POSIXct and with this as POSIXlt will the merge be good or default to character because they are different data types? The other dataset was provided to me as POSixct but as UTC.

Answer (score 1):

I found it works out doing it like this

```
as.POSIXct(strptime(df$date,format="%Y-%m-%d", tz = "UTC"))
```